# Django adding and showing favorites

Tags: django, django-views

I want the logged in user to click the favorite me button and it adds the food item to the users dashboard.

Here's the model

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    consumable_id = models.ForeignKey(Consumable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here's the template for favorite me

```
<div class="fav-me">
  <hr />
  <button id="fav-btn">Favorite Me</button>
</div>
```

Here's the template for user dashboard

```
<div class="dash-header">
  <h2>Your favorite items</h2>
  <div class="fav-item">
   {% if favorites %}
    {% for favorite in favorites %}
    <h4>Name:{{ cunsumable.name }}</h4>
    <p>${{ consumable.price }}</p>
    <button>X</button>
    {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
    <p>You don't have any favorites</p>
   {% endif %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my views

```
def dashboard(request, consumable_id):
    fav_consumables = Favorite.objects.order_by('-id')
    favorite_consumables = []

    for fav in fav_consumables:
        favorite_consumables.append(Consumable(id=fav.consumable_id))

    context = {
        'favorites' :fav_consumables
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
```